# Drop-Down selected item does not get selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlistfor

I know there are number of similar qustions around here, but non of the solutions helped me with this. Here is my case:

I have a List in my model.

```
public List<SelectListItem> Layouts { get; set; }
```

After my "Load" method, the result is as follows:

[image]

Then in my view i use this overload:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Layout, Model.Layouts, "Select a Layout", 
   new { @id = "ddLayouts", @onchange = "javascript:getExampleAddresses(this.value);" })
```

Stepping on that exact line with debbuger, i get the following result:
[image]

So far everything looks good, but when i step on the next line, the selected value gets `Selected = false`and my value does not gets selected. Does anybody have an idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You strongly binding to property `Layout` The value of `Layout` determines what is selected, not the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` (its ignored).

Set the value of `Layout` in the controller to match the value of one of the options and that option will be selected in the view

Comment: thank you! I understand now, but the problem is that the Layout value is not necessarily equal to one of the options in the drop down. I mean, if a "Custom" value of the drop down is selected on Create, a field is displayed for that Layout property, else the value of the drop down gets bounded to that Layout prop. I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. If the value of `Layout` does not match one of the option then the first option will be selected (in your case the `null` "Select a Layout" option. Thats the way model binding works - it binds to your property.

Comment: The problem is that i want to bind two inputs with the same property - Layout. The first is this drop down, the secont - one hidden input, which pops up when the user selects one given option from the drop down. I gues I have to rethink my design.

Comment: If you have 2 inputs bound to the same property, only the first one will be bound to your model when you post back (the second one will be ignored). As always, use a view model containing the properties you want to edit/display and map to and from your data model

Comment: Thanks, Stephen Muecke! You helped me to understand my problem and give me direction to solve it.